# How do I avoid echoing password (two simultaneous prompts)?

Tags: bash, password, mysql

The command I'm talking about is this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p DB | mysql -u root -p DB2
```

And here's the output:

```
Enter password: Enter password:
MYPASS
```

As far as I can tell, after I enter first password supposedly `mysqldump` turns on echo, and as a result the second password is echoed. Now that I think about it, how do they even manage to both read the password?

Comment: You can store password in `~/.my.cnf` or you can use `-pPassword` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/mysqldump-without-the-password-prompt

Comment: @Rahul: `-p MySecretPassword` would show in the output of `ps` and the history, amongst other places.

Comment: Yes, storing password in options file is probably the best way out of this. Also, I'd like to confirm if I understand right what's happening with those commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the question of "how do they even manage to both read the password?"

A device file named `/dev/tty` exists. Linux (and more modern Unix) kernels arrange for `/dev/tty` to be different for every process that has a controlling TTY.  That's all of the interactive processes, you'd have to go out of your way to write a program that doesn't have a controlling TTY. The "TTY" column of `ps -l -p $$` will show you what your shell's TTY is. `ps -el` "TTY" column will show you the controlling TTY of all processes.

You can think of `/dev/tty` as a way to get what would ordinarily be stdin, but from the keyboard associated with the controlling TTY. You can try this out with the command `cat < /dev/tty > spork` in an Xterm window. Whatever you type, up to the terminating control-D, will end up in file "spork".

A lot of FTP and SSH clients use `/dev/tty` for password input, to avoid having a password show up in the environment or other crannies. Interactive clients can do `open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)` no matter what the actual controlling TTY is, and get a file descriptor that in essence, is connected to the keyboard. Various system calls can be used to turn off echoing. You can test this by using a bash shell Xterm and running `stty -echo`. You'll have to type blind, but commands like `ls`, `ps`, etc clearly get to the shell and work. You can turn TTY echoing back on via `stty echo`.

It appears ([as per Rahul Patil above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/mysqldump-without-the-password-prompt)), that you can set a password in a file, `.my.cnf`. That file could include these lines:

```
[client]
password="my_password"
```

or maybe something like:

```
[mysql]
password="my_password"
user=root
```

[The `.my.cnf` file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) appears to be extremely flexible in specifying parameters and values common to many clients of MySQL.

Comment: In fact, I was thinking that if they both trying to read password simultaneously, how do they manage to read it correctly or why do I have to type it twice. But now I suppose the kernel simply blocks `mysql`'s `read` call, until `mysqldump`'s one gets executed. Also I believe if you add `@Rahul Patil`'s information (`~/.my.cnf` and the link) to your question, I can accept it.

Comment: @x-yuri - how about now?